Stream Studio Controller that has LCD keys with Raspberry Pi+Python
I want to use a studio keypad that has LCD keys (like this) as a keyboard raspberry pi.
There are 2 parts to this: being able to have each key display a certain image, and being able to recognize which key is getting pressed.
I haven't been able to find anything on how to do these 2 things with a Raspberry Pi - if anyone has any ideas or experience with this, plese let me know.

what is your specific question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post
